# How can a Java Predicate<T> allow a method without argument?

Tags: java, method-reference, functional-interface

From what I have studied, **Predicate** is a functional interface that has an abstract method `boolean test(T var1);`. So if I use the method reference of Java 8  and pass it to a function `getAllVegeterianDish(List<Dish> dish, Predicate<Dish> p` defined in class `VegDish` how come there is no error if I call it using `getAllVegeterianDish(menu, Dish :: isVegeterian);` as `isVegeterian()` does match the function signature of `boolean test(T var1)` and authors have specifically mentioned this in the book ***The signature of the method reference has to match the type of the context*** ( here the context is Predicate which has abstract method test that accepts 1 argument).

I have taken the following code from the book Modern Java in Action with slight modification.

```
package modernjavainaction.chap04;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Dish {

  private final String name;
  private final boolean vegetarian;
  private final int calories;
  private final Type type;

  public Dish(String name, boolean vegetarian, int calories, Type type) {
    this.name = name;
    this.vegetarian = vegetarian;
    this.calories = calories;
    this.type = type;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public boolean isVegetarian() {
    return vegetarian;
  }

  public int getCalories() {
    return calories;
  }

  public Type getType() {
    return type;
  }

 

  public enum Type {
    MEAT,
    FISH,
    OTHER
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }

  public static final List<Dish> menu = Arrays.asList(
      new Dish("pork", false, 800, Dish.Type.MEAT),
      new Dish("beef", false, 700, Dish.Type.MEAT),
      new Dish("chicken", false, 400, Dish.Type.MEAT),
      new Dish("french fries", true, 530, Dish.Type.OTHER),
      new Dish("rice", true, 350, Dish.Type.OTHER),
      new Dish("season fruit", true, 120, Dish.Type.OTHER),
      new Dish("pizza", true, 550, Dish.Type.OTHER),
      new Dish("prawns", false, 400, Dish.Type.FISH),
      new Dish("salmon", false, 450, Dish.Type.FISH)
  );

}
```

```
package modernjavainaction.chap04;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
import static modernjavainaction.chap04.Dish.menu;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class VegDish {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
      List<Dish> res = getAllVegeterianDish(menu, Dish :: isVegeterian);
      System.out.println(res);
  }


  public static List<Dish> getAllVegeterianDish(List<Dish> dish, Predicate<Dish> p) {
      List<Dish> vegan = new ArrayList<>();
      for(Dish d : dish) {
          if(p.test(d)) {
              vegan.add(d);
          }
      }
      return vegan;
  }
```

Edit:
So I figured out there was a gap in my understanding and in order to understand the method reference first we should know what its equivalent lambda is, which is,

```
List<Dish> res = getAllVegeterianDish(menu, (Dish d) -> d.isVegeterian());
```

where d is an arbitrary object in the Veg class. Now if you do not know what an arbitrary object is please read up different types of method reference in the oracle docs and over there check the table "Kinds of Method References" [oracle docs for method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).
Let me tell you what I understood by the term arbitrary. It means that you are using an object of some other class in the current class. So in our lambda example, we are using Object d of type Dish in the Veg class.

Now the rule to transform lambda to method reference of such type is

```
            Lambda
            (args0) -> args0.instanceMethod()

            Method Reference
            ClassName :: instanceMethod

            where args0 is of type Class Name
```

Now using the above blueprint lets replace our lambda with method reference
args0 --> d
instanceMethod() --> isVegeterian()

So the corresponding Method reference is

```
List<Dish> res = getAllVegeterianDish(menu, Dish :: isVegeterian);
```

The above blueprint I got from the book Modern Java in Action.

Comment: @samabcde does it mean when I write p.test(d) it is as good as saying d.isVegeterian() ? which java does it behind the scenes?

Comment: For first question, your assumption is correct. For second question, I don't know how java implement this behind the scene, you can post another question.